# Can you make beef and noodles with a beef stew seasoning packet?

Tags: beef, seasoning, noodles

I haven't made beef and noodles in a while but I have this beef stew seasoning packet and wanted to try that instead of beef broth or the beef cubes. Would this work? How much water would I need? I am just making a regular amount with one package of noodles and a can of shredded beef.

Comment: What's a "beef stew seasoning packet"? Can you include a photo and ingredients?

Comment: It's a Mccormick beef stew seasoning packet. I'm not at home so I can't take a photo

Comment: https://www.mccormick.com/spices-and-flavors/recipe-mixes/home-style-classics/beef-stew-seasoning-mix this one?

Comment: Yep! That one exactly

Answer (score 1):

So you have [this seasoning mix](https://www.mccormick.com/spices-and-flavors/recipe-mixes/home-style-classics/beef-stew-seasoning-mix), as [per comments](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/122002/can-you-make-beef-and-noodles-with-a-beef-stew-seasoning-packet?noredirect=1#comment199506_122002).

Ingredients are, *with my comments*:

- Corn Starch *thickener*
- Salt *obvious*
- Onion *goes well with beef, found in most "beef noodles" recipes I glanced at*
- Sugar *a bit of it does wonders to beef taste, in my opinion*
- Spices (Including Paprika, Black Pepper, Thyme) *that's what I add to my beef, too*
- Tomato *questionable, but I see how it can be good*
- Hydrolyzed Corn Gluten *thickener, mouthfeel*
- Soy Protein and Wheat Gluten *as above*
- Caramel Color *obvious*
- Citric Acid
- Xanthan Gum (Thickener).

So will this make a beef noodles as a stand in replacement? I think not. It doesn't have any beef taste on its own. And if you will try to boil canned beef with it long enough for taste to mix in, you will overcook your beef.

Consider either using these ingredients separately, as they were probably meant to be used, or treating it as an experiment. Personally, I like beef overcooked in sauce to the point there are no longer visible beef pieces, just one smooth thick sauce. But that's quite far from what you would usually call beef noodles.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the ingredients, I would say no.

The seasoning packet is designed to work with raw meat and does not contain any beef flavor on its own.

Canned, cooked meat will not impart enough flavor to give you anything other than starchy paste with shredded beef and noodles in it.